# Error in calling multipolyfit(x,y ,degree) for multivariable polynomial curve fit. "multipolyfit module is not callable"

Tags: python-3.x, curve-fitting

I have been trying to use 'Multipolyfit' for generating polynomial (degree 6) curve fit for multivariable dataset.I had downloaded the 'Multipolyfit' from Github and put it in the same folder I was writing my codes in.But,the following error keeps popping up saying 'multipolyfit module is not callable'.

Part of code:

```
from multipolyfit import multipolyfit

deg=6

coeffs = multipolyfit(x, y, deg)
```

x and y are arrays.
No matter what the datatype of x and y ,the same error keeps coming up each and every time.I have searched a lot of online resources and codes using this function ,but could not repair this error.Can anyone please help me out with this.Alternatively ,is there a better/easier method to do the same job?

Comment: Could you add the data you try to fit?

Comment: I have torque values for a a switched reluctance motor at different current and phase angles.Current and phase angles are varied in certain limits,with 24 levels for current and 8 levels for phase angle.So,I want to model the torqu as a function of current and phase angle.I cant post the exact data due to confidentiality issues.

Comment: Without data it is a bit difficult to help; then maybe post just parts of the data or modified data.

Comment: @Cleb Sorry for replying late.The sample data is as follows:         248 DATAPOINTS               (Angle,  Current,  torque_z)-->
(0 ,   6, 1.273805328)
(0,   12 5.094693448)
(0,  18, 11.42940884)
(0,  24 19.98767583)